# query for my first row admin for never delete

Tags: php, javascript, sql, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent deletion of the first row in table (PostgreSQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810180/how-to-prevent-deletion-of-the-first-row-in-table-postgresql)

i have a table users in which my first row is admin as seen below

```
               guid                | username |             password             |         firstname | lastname  | location | emailaddress  |   userrole
-----------------------------------+----------+----------------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------
 2644885344cecd6f2973b35.63257615  | admin    | 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 |         System    | Generated |          |               | administrator
 11980380874dc3b542363526.78672935 | gds      | a5f9a8e4d375eb82ca70f7ab7b08ec7c |         gag       | gsdg      | dsf      | fdsf@fdsd.jgh | administrator
(2 rows)
```

can anyone sugest me the query for my first row admin for never delete ... means this

can not be deleted if user goes to delete then an alert generate "do not delete

admin"

nd if user want to delete 2nd,3rd,4th or any other row then it is posible ..... i m using php

Comment: Why don't you just add a check in your PHP code to prevent this?

Comment: @wimvds: Because PHP won't stop someone with direct access to the database.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Ok, but if the person has direct access to the DB then chances are that if he can delete the row he'll also be able to drop the trigger that prevents the deletion of the row.

Comment: @wimvds: Account permissions can be managed -- having an account doesn't mean the account is root/equivalent.  Having DB connection information is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use following simply mysql query...

```
DELETE FROM users_tbl WHERE id = 2 AND username != 'admin';
```

It would never delete admin row.

Comment: You swapped userrole and username: DELETE FROM users_tbl WHERE id = 2 AND username != 'admin';

Comment: @Dary_ever I have updated my answer, please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Define a [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) on the table, tied to the before delete event that calls a stored procedure where you check the ID they want to delete against the ID you stored in the DB for the admin. If they match, then [raise an exception](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) to stop postgresql from executing the actual delete.