# creating an alert for particular row 1 and not to del from database postgre

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql

I have an user table like this:-

```
               guid                | username |             password             | firstname | lastname  | location | emailaddress |   userrole
-----------------------------------+----------+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------
 8024259764dc3e8ee0fb6f5.84107784  | james    | 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b | james     | bond      | NY       | ny@live.com  | administrator
 18689183644dc3e91571a364.71859328 | saty     | 250cf8b51c773f3f8dc8b4be867a9a02 | saty      | john      | NY       | hk@fd.com    | administrator
 2644885344cecd6f2973b35.63257615  | admin    | 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 | System    | Generated |          |              | administrator
(3 rows)
```

now my postgre query for delete the row ....

```
$query = "delete from users where username!= 'admin' and guid='".$guid."'";
    $result = pg_query($conn, $query);

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Cannot delete this .\n It is system generated(s).");
            </script>       
      <?php
```

when someone try to delete username from my page userlist.php .. this alert generate for only for admin  and continue on this page..and also admin never delete it is default ...
otherwise delete the data from database except admin
help me

Comment: This should not be done with javascript ... the javascript is executed on client side so you can't rely on it.

Comment: @ Teneff:- it works man but this alert show for al users ... i want to show that alert only for admin when some one goes to del the admin..i want that admin never delete while other username delete ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [query for my first row admin for never delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908897/query-for-my-first-row-admin-for-never-delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not lookup the username for the `$guid` **before** you try to delete anything, just a simple bit of SQL like this:

```
$query = "select username from users where guid = '" . $guid . "'";
# Execute this, pull out the username, and see if it is "admin".
```

Then, if `username` is "admin", show your alert; if there `username` is not "admin", do your deletion. You seem to be trying to do too many different things at the same time when you should be doing things one at a time, there's nothing wrong with doing two queries when you need to do two different things.

And I hope your sanitizing and quoting `$guid` somewhere to prevent SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pg_affected_rows to query how many rows were actually deleted. When it's zero it you are sure the guid existed it must be because the guid belonged to the admin user.

```
if (pg_affected_rows($result)) {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Cannot delete this .\n It is system generated(s).");
        </script>       
    <?php
}
```

Personally I would choose a design where you have a superuser with a fixed guid like 0 or 1 so you don't have test and rely on the name. What happens when a user uses the name admin or succeeds in changing his name to admin because of a bug somewhere?