# creating an alert and continue on this page after alert

Tags: php, javascript, sql, postgresql

I have an user table like this:-

```
               guid                | username |             password             | firstname | lastname  | location | emailad
dress |   userrole
-----------------------------------+----------+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------
------+---------------
 8024259764dc3e8ee0fb6f5.84107784  | james    | 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b | james     | bond      | NY       | ny@live
.com  | administrator
 18689183644dc3e91571a364.71859328 | saty     | 250cf8b51c773f3f8dc8b4be867a9a02 | saty      | john      | NY       | hk@fd.c
om    | administrator
 2644885344cecd6f2973b35.63257615  | admin    | 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 | System    | Generated |          |
      | administrator
(3 rows)
```

now my postgre query for delete the row ....

```
$query = "delete from users where username!= 'admin' and guid='".$guid."'";
    $result = pg_query($conn, $query);


    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Cannot delete this .\n It is system generated(s).");
        </script>       
  <?php
```

(1)when I delete the user name one by one then delete occurs in my page userlist.php, I donot want to delete admin so i use `username!= 'admin'` in where condition as shown above.
(2)now when I del any username(3 rows) from user table then alert occurs & it delete from userlist.php after that my page userlist.php is blank. Finaly when i refresh the page then my admin username seen..

so can anyone put the best condition in my coding.
i donot want to refresh the page actualy i want my page continue after alert so plz help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent deletion of the first row in table (PostgreSQL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810180/how-to-prevent-deletion-of-the-first-row-in-table-postgresql)

Comment: This looks surprisingly similar to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908897/query-for-my-first-row-admin-for-never-delete
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810180/how-to-prevent-deletion-of-the-first-row-in-table-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use this**

```
$query = "select username from users where username='admin' and guid='".$guid."'";  
    $result = pg_query($conn, $query);
    AddLog("deleteUI.php","Query : ".$query,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 

    //if (pg_affected_rows($result))
        {
            AddLog("deleteUI.php","Error !!! COMMIT",ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
            pg_close($conn);
            ?>      
        <script type="text/javascript">            
        alert("Cannot delete the built-in admin user.");
        </script>           
        <?php 
        exit();
        }
```

&  delete query like that

```
$query = "delete from users where guid='".$guid."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you do not execute a SELECT-query after the delete. Make sure your list is BELOW the delete query, so your page would be something like

```
if($_GET['delete']) {
  // delete query
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM";
// rest for getting the complete list.
```

This way you should get your refreshed list..

//edit:
oh and perhaps adding `return true;` after the alert might continue execution the page, since javascript might block further execution on an alert (not sure if it returns false by default).